# SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(error database_closed))

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

## hello

I have problem with inserting in insertTask method it throw an exception 
`SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(error database_closed))`  
on this line of code in insertTask method : 
`final taskId = await db.insert(tableTasks, taskMap);`

so I'm using the Sqflit package in flutter, this is the `DatabaseHelper`  class:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:almedad/models/task_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import '../models/user_model.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  // Database name
  static const _databaseName = "mate.db";
  // Database version
  static const _databaseVersion = 1;
  // Tables
  static const tableUsers = 'users';
  static const tableSettings = 'settings';
  static const tableTasks = 'tasks';
  static const tableTasksSteps = 'tasksSteps';
  // Columns
  //----------------Users-------------------------
  static const columnId = 'id_user';
  static const columnUsername = 'username';
  static const columnEmail = 'email';
  static const columnPassword = 'password';
  //-----------------------------------------------

  //----------------Settings-----------------------
  static const columnSettingsId = 'id_settings';
  static const columnIsDark = 'is_dark';
  static const columnLanguage = 'language';
  static const columnIdUser = 'id_user';
  //-----------------------------------------------

  //----------------tasks-----------------------
  static const columntasksId = 'id_task';
  static const columnUsersId = 'id_user';
  static const columnCatagory = 'category';
  static const columnTitle = 'title';
  static const columnStartDate = 'start_date';
  static const columnEndDate = 'end_date';
  static const columnCreatedDate = 'created_date';
  //-----------------------------------------------
  static final List<String> values = [
    columntasksId,
    columnUsersId,
    columnCatagory,
    columnTitle,
    columnStartDate,
    columnEndDate,
    columnCreatedDate
  ];
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static Database? _database;

  // check if the database it's already exists
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database!;
  }

//innitlizing the database
  // Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
  //   final path = await getDatabasesPath();
  //   final fullPath = join(path, _databaseName);
  //   return await openDatabase(fullPath,
  //       version: _databaseVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  // }
  // Initializing the database
  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    final path = await getDatabasesPath();
    final fullPath = join(path, _databaseName);
    final database = await openDatabase(
      fullPath,
      version: _databaseVersion,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
    return database;
  }

  // Creating databse schema
  Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE $tableUsers (
$columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
$columnUsername TEXT ,
$columnEmail TEXT,
$columnPassword TEXTs
)
''');
    await db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE $tableSettings (
$columnSettingsId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
$columnIsDark INTEGER ,
$columnLanguage TEXT ,
$columnIdUser INTEGER ,
FOREIGN KEY ($columnIdUser) REFERENCES $tableUsers ($columnId)
)
''');
    await db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE $tableTasks (
$columntasksId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
$columnTitle TEXT ,
$columnCatagory TEXT ,
$columnStartDate DATE ,
$columnEndDate DATE ,
$columnCreatedDate DATE ,
$columnUsersId INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY ($columnUsersId) REFERENCES $tableUsers ($columnId)
)
''');
  }

  // Check if the user exists in the database
  Future<bool> checkUserExists(String username, String email) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final res = await db.rawQuery(
        'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableUsers WHERE $columnUsername = ? OR $columnEmail = ?',
        [username, email]);
    final count = res[0]['COUNT(*)'] as int;
    return count > 0;
  }

  // Insert method
  Future<int> insertUser(User user) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final userMap = {
      columnUsername: user.username,
      columnEmail: user.email,
      columnPassword: user.password,
    };
    return db.insert(tableUsers, userMap);
  }

  // Define a method to insert new settings for a user into the database
  Future<int> insertSettings(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    return db.insert(tableSettings, row);
  } // Define a method to insert new settings for a user into the database

  // // Insert task method
  // Future<int> insertTask(Task task) async {
  //   final db = await instance.database; // Open the database connection
  //   final taskMap = {
  //     columntasksId: task.idTask,
  //     columnUsersId: task.idUser,
  //     columnCatagory: task.category,
  //     columnTitle: task.title,
  //     columnStartDate: task.startDate,
  //     columnEndDate: task.endDate,
  //     columnCreatedDate: task.createdDate
  //   };

  //   return db.insert(tableTasks, taskMap);
  // }
  Future<int> insertTask(Task task) async {
    final db = await instance.database; // Open the database connection
    try {
      final taskMap = {
        columntasksId: task.idTask,
        columnUsersId: task.idUser,
        columnCatagory: task.category,
        columnTitle: task.title,
        columnStartDate: task.startDate,
        columnEndDate: task.endDate,
        columnCreatedDate: task.createdDate,
      };
      final taskId = await db.insert(tableTasks, taskMap); // Insert the task
      return taskId;
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Error inserting task: $e');
      }
      rethrow; // Rethrow the exception to handle it elsewhere if needed
    } finally {
      // Close the database connection
      await db.close();
    }
  }

  Future<Task> readTask(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final maps = await db.query(tableTasks,
        columns: DatabaseHelper.values,
        where: '${DatabaseHelper.columntasksId}=?',
        whereArgs: [id]);
    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {
      return Task.fromJson(maps.first);
    } else {
      throw Exception('ID is not found');
    }
  }

  // Query
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllUsers(
      String email, String password) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    return db.query(tableUsers);
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllSettings() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    return db.query(tableSettings);
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllTasks() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    return db.query(tableTasks);
  }

  // Bridge
  // Define a method to query the settings for a specific user from the database
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> querySettingsForUser(int userId) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final rows = await db.query(
      tableSettings,
      where: '$columnIdUser = ?',
      whereArgs: [userId],
      limit: 1,
    );
    if (rows.isNotEmpty) {
      return rows.first;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<int> deleteTask(int idTask) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(
      tableTasks,
      where: '$columntasksId = ? AND $columnId = ?',
      whereArgs: [idTask],
    );
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryTasksForUser(int userId) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(
      tableTasks,
      where: '$columnId = ?',
      whereArgs: [userId],
    );
  }

  // Update
  Future<int> updateUser(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final id = row[columnId];
    return db.update(tableUsers, row, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  // Update
  Future<int> updateTask(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final id = row[columntasksId];
    return db
        .update(tableTasks, row, where: '$columntasksId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  // Define a method to update a user's settings in the database
  Future<int> updateSettings(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final id = row[columnSettingsId];
    return db.update(
      tableSettings,
      row,
      where: '$columnSettingsId = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

// //to close database
//   Future close() async {
//     final db = await instance.database;
//     db.close();
//   }
}
```

and this is the `TaskProvider` class :

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../helpers/database_helper.dart';
import '../models/task_model.dart';
import '../models/user_model.dart';

class TaskProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

  List<Task> _tasks = [];
  int? _currentUserId;
  User? userId;

  List<Task> get tasks => _tasks;

  // void setCurrentUserId(User userId) {

  // }

  Future<void> addTask(Task task) async {
    userId = User(idUser: _currentUserId ?? 0);
    if (userId == null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Current user ID is null');
      return;
    }

    final newTask = task.copyWith(idUser: userId!.idUser);
    final id = await dbHelper.insertTask(newTask);

    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (id != null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Task added successfully');
      _tasks.add(newTask.copyWith(idTask: id));
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Failed to add task');
    }
  }

  Future<void> editTask(Task task) async {
    if (_currentUserId == null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Current user ID is null');
      return;
    }

    final updatedTask = task.copyWith(idUser: _currentUserId!);
    final rowsAffected = await dbHelper.updateTask(updatedTask.toMap());

    if (rowsAffected > 0) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Task updated successfully');
      final index = _tasks.indexWhere((t) => t.idTask == task.idTask);
      _tasks[index] = updatedTask;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Failed to update task');
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteTask(int idTask) async {
    if (_currentUserId == null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Current user ID is null');
      return;
    }

    final rowsAffected = await dbHelper.deleteTask(idTask);

    if (rowsAffected > 0) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Task deleted successfully');
      _tasks.removeWhere((t) => t.idTask == idTask);
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Failed to delete task');
    }
  }

  Future<void> presentTasks() async {
    if (_currentUserId == null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Current user ID is null');
      return;
    }

    final tasksMap = await dbHelper.queryTasksForUser(_currentUserId!);

    if (tasksMap.isNotEmpty) {
      _tasks = tasksMap.map((t) => Task.fromMap(t)).toList();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  String formatDate(DateTime date) {
    return DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(date);
  }
}
```

I did try to open the database and then close it but nothing worked, because before this exception an it was throw another exception says `Current user ID is null` , so can you help me to fix it !